# Embedding a Streamlit App into an Existing React.js Application through an iFrame

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, iframe, streamlit

I have an existing React.js application and I want to integrate a Streamlit app into it. Is it possible to achieve this by using an iFrame? My goal is to leverage the data analysis and visualization capabilities provided by Streamlit app.

Has anyone attempted to embed a Streamlit app into a React.js application using an iFrame before? If so, I would appreciate any insights into the best approach and potential challenges to be aware of.

If embedding Streamlit via an iFrame is not recommended, are there any alternative methods to achieve this integration without rewriting the entire application? Any suggestions or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can embed a Streamlit app in an iframe via the following (this can also be found in our docs [here](https://docs.streamlit.io/streamlit-community-cloud/get-started/embed-your-app)):

```
<iframe
  src="https://30days.streamlit.app/?embed=true"
  height="450"
  style="width:100%;border:none;"
></iframe>
```